# AWS ECS Timeout on RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, digital-ocean, amazon-ecs, apachebench

I've two clones of the same API: one hosted in Digital Ocean, and one on AWS ECS. They're based on Nginx+PHP-FPM on docker. The API on DO has no load balancer, while the one on AWS has an ALB upfront. This two APIs make requests to the same DB on AWS RDS. Now: I've tried Apache Benchmark to flood the API on AWS:

```
ab -n 5000 -c 500 "https://myurl.com"
```

If I try to make additional requests (through an APP GUI) while the bench is in progress, all I got is timeouts: the "fun" part is that if I use the API on DO I got responses very quickly. So, my first try was to give more resources to AWS ECS web serving tasks. No way, even with 20 tasks with 2048 CPU units and lot of RAM, I got the same result. At this point I noticed the RDS CPU going 99%, so this could be the problem, BUT I can't really explain why DO is working normally, so I don't want just increase RDS without knowing why. I've no clue what's going on, anyone could please clarify this behaviour? Many thanks in advance. Please feel free to ask more info if needed.

Comment: Maybe you have some caching configured in your DO setup?

Comment: I've never configured anything related to cache. How can I investigate that?

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the query cache on the RDS when you're benchmarking, if you're using mysql engine `SET GLOBAL query_cache_size = 0;` or you can [edit the parameter group](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/130170/how-to-change-query-cache-type-to-2-in-aws-rds) of the RDS instance to make the change more permanent (Don't do this for production systems).

Also RDS provide 7 days free retention for [performance insights](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/performance-insights/) which might enable you to troubleshoot the performance a bit better. You can of course enable [slow query logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Concepts.MySQL.html), to investigate whether a particular query is taking a long time.

Hope this helps, good luck!